# Проблема с компонентом textBox

Tags: c#, winforms

Делаю простой файловый менеджер. Папки/файлы отображает компонент webBrowser. Сверху над webBrowser отображается адрес в textBox и его можно редактировать самостоятельно, тем самым переходя по нужному адресу. 
Проблема в том, что когда отображается адрес C:\ и если я допишу C:\Windows я соответственно перейду в папку C:\Windows, но если после Windows поставить новый слэш, то он сам стирается и курсор ввода сам переходит в начало всей строчки.
Решается тем что нужно намеренно сделать ошибку, написав C:\WindowsS, после поставить слэш и прописать следующую папку C:\WindowsS\Help, а потом убрать ошибку C:\Windows\Help, тогда переходит.
Подскажите, как исправить это?

```
private bool adds = true;
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Directory.Exists(textBox1.Text) || (File.Exists(textBox1.Text)))
        {
            adds = false;
            webBrowser1.Navigate(textBox1.Text);
            adds = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: TextBox.Changed срабатывает на ввод каждого символа, отсюда и проблема. Зачем вам постоянно мониторить ввод пользователя? пусть вводит что хочет, по нажатию enter проверите.

Comment: Так быстрее и пользователю не нужно нажимать что-то еще.

Comment: А ничего, что путь к папке валиден и с завершающим слешем и без него. Во всяком случае в текущей реализации  это не обрабатывается никак

Comment: Ну и ещё, не нарушайте устоявшиеся стереотипы поведения интерфейса, пользователи спасибо не скажут, разве что у них выбора не останется, как было с офисом 2007 и рибоном

Comment: Не подскажете, как сделать так, как вы сказали - по нажатию enter или button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 Выносим в отдельный метод код из обработчика

```
private void _navigate(string path)
{
    if (Directory.Exists(path) || (File.Exists(path)))
        webBrowser1.Navigate(path);
}
```

2 Подписываемся на событие TextBox.KeyDown

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode < Keys.Enter)
    {
        var tb = (TextBox)sender;
        _navigate(tb.Text) 
    }
}
```

3 Подписываемся на событие кнопки Click

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   _navigate(textBox1.Text);
}
```

4 При потере фокуса, TextBox забывает положение курсора и возвращает его в начало строки когда фокус возвращается к нему. Возвращаем курсор в конец текста, если TextBox терял фокус.

```
private void textBox1_GotFocus(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var tb = (TextBox)sender;
    tb.SelectionStart = tb.Text.Length > 0 ? tb.Text.Length-1 : 0;
    tb.SelectionLength = 0
}
```

5 Profit!

---

`TextBox.Changed` срабатывает на ввод каждого символа, поэтому на это событие можно повесить предварительную валидацию введенного пути, и подкрашивать фон другим цветом, если пользователь ввел чушь. Только учтите, что `File.Exists` и `Directory.Exists` использовать для этого не стоит, т.к. они могут работать медленно, все таки к диску обращаются. Лучше составить словарь запрещенных символов и проверять последний введенный символ. Хотя если вы хотите сделать аналог autocomplete, то без обращений к диску не получится, но это уже другая история.

---

Не перегружайте логикой обработчики событий, оставьте там только логику связанную непосредственно с событием. Делайте отдельные методы для выполнения определенных действий и вызывайте эти методы из обработчиков. Если таких методов становится много, есть смысл думать о выносе логики не связанной непосредственно с контролами формы в отдельный класс.